# Last night, all the villagers disappeared from the village

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have set up a server for some friends and I. Last night, someone went to the village and all villagers were gone.

After searching a bit, there were a single zombie and a single skeleton in the village. Is it possible that they killed everyone?

- Official minecraft server 1.8, 0 mods/plugins
- Fences all around the village

I already saw [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/167468/villagers-disappeared) but I don't have any mod.

Comment: It's quite likely that the zombie ate your villagers' brains :(

Comment: You say someone went to the village, I remember reading about NPC's (mobs and villagers) did not load WITH chunks, so if a chunk was unloaded, it could have despawned the villagers. I am sure it was for mobs, but not sure about villagers.

Comment: Villagers do not despawn. But villagers are absolutely defenseless, so one zombie is all that is needed to exterminate a whole village. Skeletons are absolutely not interested in villagers, by the way, but zombies like them very very much.

Comment: This is a wonderful novel starter. (The title that is), But yes the zombies ate the villagers brains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if the village is fenced in,  mobs can spawn if it is not properly lit up. Even a tiny space that is not bright enough can support a zombie,  who could do quite a bit of damage. I don't know your setup though,  so this is just a guess on **your** problem.

Comment: Even if the village is fully lit up, zombie siege(http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Zombie_siege) can randomly happen. It didn't for a long time due to a bug(https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-7432) and is fixed in 1.8. To prevent villagers from being killed completely, you may need to build iron golems.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly they despawned. The same thing happened to me: no villagers and a zombie in the well with a door in its hand.

Think it was daylight. And,yes,it is possible for the zombie to kill everyone.(Skeletons don't attack villagers).

This thing could have happened especially if the villagers entered in a few houses or a single house. The zombie could have broken the door and blocked the villagers while getting out.